# Regularity on $\mathbb{T}^3$ of the "functional average" of a map $S : C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, schwartz-distributions, gaussian

For simplicity, let $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$ be the real Frechet space of periodic smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Here, $\mathbb{T}^3$ is the $3$-dimensional torus.

For a fixed element $\omega \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$ I constructed a Gaussian measure $\mu_\omega$ on $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$ whose characteristic functional is given by
\begin{equation}
\widehat{\mu_\omega}(T)=e^{\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{T}^3} (T*w)(x) [\Delta (T*w)](x) dx}
\end{equation}
where $T$ is an arbitrary continuous linear functional on $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3)$. In fact, it is known that $T$ can be identified with a periodic distribution on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now, let $S : C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$ be a continuous map (NOT necessarily linear) such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})} \lVert S(u) \rVert d\mu_{\omega}(u) < \infty
\end{equation}

Then, the functional integration
\begin{equation}
\overline{S}:=\int_{C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})}  S(u)  d\mu_{\omega}(u) 
\end{equation}
exists in the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$.

Now, my question is as follows:

How "regular" is $\overline{S}$ as a periodic function on $\mathbb{R}^3$? Is it possible to establish continuity or even smoothness of $\overline{S}(x)$ with respect to $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$?

This kind of question seems somewhat familiar to me, but I cannot really find a relevant reference. Could anyone please help me?